# Relative risk estimation in R using a loglink fuction from Logbin package

Tags: r

I want to estimate the relative risk using the logbin function from the logbin-package in R. Unfortunately I find a discrepancy between the estimated rr and the rr calculated manually.
Each StudyID is assigned to a group and has a dichotomous outcome:

I used the following dataset

```
Study_ID <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
Group <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
Outcome <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)

Data_logbin <- bind_cols(Study_ID, Group, Outcome)
Data_logbin <- setNames(Data_logbin, c("Study_ID", "Group", "Outcome"))
```

If I calculate the relative risk and odds ratio manually, I get the following results:

```
#Manually ---- 
#OR = (a/b)/(c/d) = (1/3)/(2/4)
#rr = (a/a+b)/(c/c+d) = (1/4)/(2/6)

or <- (1/3)/(2/4)  # 0.667
rr <- (1/4)/(2/6)  # 0.750
```

I tried to reproduce this with the following script:

```
fit.glm_Outcome_logbin_OR <- glm(Outcome ~ Group, 
                       family = binomial, data = Data_logbin)
summary(fit.glm_Outcome_logbin_OR)
exp(coef(fit.glm_Outcome_logbin_OR)) #0.667 = OR

fit.glm_Outcome_logbin_rr <- glm(Outcome ~ Group, 
                 family = binomial(log), data = Data_logbin)
summary(fit.glm_Outcome_logbin_rr)
exp(coef(fit.glm_Outcome_logbin_rr)) #0.889 = ??

fit.logbin_Outcome <- logbin(Outcome ~ Group, data = Data_logbin)
summary(fit.logbin_Outcome)
exp(coef(fit.logbin_Outcome)) #0.889 = ??
```

There is a discrepancy between the RR calculated manually and while using the script. I do not understand why the estimated RR is 0.889.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Firstly, there is no problem with the logbin R-package specifically since you get the same answer than glm (though logbin encompasses optimization methods more suitable for this problem). Now, the question is why is this not spitting out the classical measure of RR? You assume that exp(coefficients) following a logistic regression with a log link function, will give you RR_MLE (I cannot verify this anywhere). It is probably lack of understanding about the model itself. But this is a stats question and should be posted elsewhere (try: https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are just miscalculating the relative risk in your initial calculations by hand. I think you have your table flipped. If you look at it, I believe it should be:

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | 1 | 3 |
| **1** | 2 | 4 |

So, you should have:

OR: (4/2)/(3/1) == (1/3)/(2/4) = .667

RR: (4/6)/(3/4) = .889

It just worked out that your odds ratio was correct based on how odds ratios are calculated but that isn't the case for relative risk ratio. I hope this helps and please correct me if I am wrong!